# Skype for Business: HTML link URI to call/chat?

Tags: skype-for-business

There's a lot of solutions for creating HTML links for Skype (href="skype:username") but I can't find any for Skype for Business that will work. (href="sip:

Any ideas on how to open a chat window from a webpage for Skype for Business?

Answer (score 13):

This is a method .

```
 <div id=skypecallbox>
        <a href="skype:live:skype.charlie.brown?chat">Chat - Blockhead (old skype)</a><br />
        <a href="sip:charie.brown@peanuts.com">Chat - Blockhead (new skypeFB)</a>
    </div>
```

Also i just checked, for business they would use this extension:

```
sip:<xyz@domain.com>
```